# sql select to start with a particular record

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there any way to write a select record starting with a particular record?  Suppose I have an table with following data:

```
 SNO    ID  ISSUE
 ----------------------
   1    A1  unknown
   2    A2  some_issue
   3    A1  unknown2
   4    B1  some_issue2
   5    B3  ISSUE4
   6    B1  ISSUE4
```

Can I write a select to start showing records starting with B1 and then the remaining records? The output should be something like this:

```
4    B1  some_issue2
6    B1  ISSUE4
1    A1  unknown
2    A2  some_issue
3    A1  unknown2
5    B3  ISSUE4
```

It doesn't matter if B3 is last, just that B1 should be displayed first.

Comment: How do you determine which "value" should come first? weight, personal selction?

Comment: its MySQL
@astander: ID should start with B1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of different options depending on what you 'know' ahead of time (i.e. the id of the record you want to be first, the sno, etc.):

Union approach:

```
select   1 as sortOrder, SNO, ID, ISSUE
from     tableName
where    ID = 'B1'
union all
select   2 as sortOrder, SNO, ID, ISSUE
from     tableName
where    ID <> 'B1'
order by sortOrder;
```

Case statement in order by:

```
select   SNO, ID, ISSUE
from     tableName
order by case when ID = 'B1' then 1 else 2 end;
```

You could also consider using temp tables, cte's, etc., but those approaches would *likely* be less performant...try a couple different approaches in your environment to see which works best.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL, you could either use IF() in an ORDER BY clause...

```
SELECT SNO, ID, ISSUE FROM table ORDER BY IF( ID = 'B1', 0, 1 );
```

... or you could define a function that imposes your sort order...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION my_sort_order( ID VARCHAR(2), EXPECTED VARCHAR(2) )
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN IF( ID = EXPECTED, 0, 1 );
END$$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT SNO, ID, ISSUE FROM table ORDER BY my_sort_sort( ID, 'B1' );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table1
where id = 'B1'
union all
select * from table1
where id <> 'B1'
```

Comment: Not sure (i.e. I didn't down vote), but I would assume it may be because to guarantee sort order you'd need to add an "order by" clause (i.e. there would be potential for this query to return data in any order). Not sure that's worth a downvote or not, particularly without a comment, but that's my guess.

Comment: people might just be "playing the game" (down vote others to get theirs positioned better)